# JS Modified Ternary Operator?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-operator

I am aware of the JavaScript ternary operator `condition? optionA : optionB` and now I am seeing `{{option: condition}}` in Vue, and the behaviour seems to be that if `condition` holds the assignment is `option`, otherwise the assignment is empty. Is this 'binary' operator `:` something general for JS or particular to Vue?

The actual code:

`<span :class="{ done: todo.done }">{{ todo.text }}</span>`

where

`.done { text-decoration: line-through; }`

is a CSS and `todo.done` is a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an operator but regular object literal syntax. Vue `class` attribute [supports objects](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes) for conditional class lists, where boolean value determines whether class name from a key is added to a list or omitted.

This behaviour is similar to popular [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package that serves the same purpose in React ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a binary operator, you should choose `||`. This object syntax is not specific to vue but the usage is: What this code is saying is "Set the attribute `done` of the object bound to the class to `todo.done`, and vue will infer to add or not to add the class of the object parameter (in your case it is `done`).